# Possible memory corruption using estimateAffinePartial2D

Tags: c++, opencv

I have started using estimateAffinePartial2D as a replacement for the deprecated estimateRigidTransform method. The application is aligning the 5 landmarks generated by a face detection algorithm.

Previously the rigid transform would return None if it was unable to solve the estimation instead of a transform vector. EAP2D always returns a vector.

The problem is that if EAP2D is unable to produce a solution (if a face is poorly aligned) everything the method returns after that point is garbage. I have double checked this by taking landmark values where it was generating invalid transform matrices, restarted it and passed in the same values and it generated a valid transform matrix.

Here is the output for the same set of landmarks:

```
   actual landmarks: 
   [[[ 65.3148   96.60192]
      [152.09814  97.58065]
      [122.19773 140.87932]
      [ 80.71128 196.89061]
      [145.18759 197.73586]]]
   reference landmarks:
   [[[70.7299 92.2041]
      [70.7299 92.2041]
      [70.7299 92.2041]
      [70.7299 92.2041]
      [70.7299 92.2041]]]

   Output after being unable to compute a landmark:
   [[-0.         -0.         70.72989655],
     [ 0.         -0.         92.20410156]]

   Output after restart (with same input):
   [[ 4.11637995e-01, -6.70766338e-03,  1.13927864e+01],
     [ 6.70766338e-03,  4.11637995e-01,  1.06043865e+01]]
```

The code is as follows:

```
# Align the image
# transform = cv.estimateRigidTransform(landmarks, self.reference_landmarks, False)
# Partial affine based on this post:
# http://answers.opencv.org/question/123476/estimateaffinepartial2d-and-estimateaffine2d/
transform = cv.estimateAffinePartial2D(landmarks, self.reference_landmarks)
image = cv.warpAffine(image, transform[0], self.cnn_input_size)
```

The rest of the code is based on [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/05/30/displaying-a-video-feed-with-opencv-and-tkinter/)which is using threading to update the video on a tkinter GUI.

One other detail that makes me think it is memory corruption. I had to test the rigidTransform and the EAP2D separately. If I computed a bad transform with EAP2D it would also effect the output of thew rigidTransform, even though they were being stored in separate variables!

I am using the cv2 wrapper and I am having this problem with both 3.4 and 4.0

Any idea what could be going on here under the hood?

Comment: Please show your code. Also your description sounds as if you use Python? None at least is not a "thing" in C++.